# how to adjust function location in a LLVM Module

Tags: c++, function, llvm, compiler-optimization, elf

I know how to parse a module from a LLVM bitcode image and how to iterate over the function definitions.

Now, I want to do a reordering to the functions to improve the locality between some functions that is measured to have closer relations with each other.

```cpp
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/CFG.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
using namespace llvm;
constexpr const char TEST_FILE[] = "some-file";
std::vector<std::string> symbol_order {};
int some_function() {
    auto context = LLVMContext{};
    SMDiagnostic err;
    auto module = parseIRFile(TEST_FILE, err, context);

    // get all functions and adjust order according to symbol order
    // wrtie back to a valid module bitcode file

}
```

It turns out to be hard because I may need to close the function and insert them by order, which is beyond my current knowledge.

Before I really turn myself into this question, I have some more concerns:

1. will the order of the definitions in IR file effectively affect the final ELF output?
2. I am currently writing an executable directly operate on the IR files; will it be more proper to write a module pass?

update

I see a possible way to sort the function is:

```cpp
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/CFG.h>
#include <llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeWriter.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <absl/container/flat_hash_map.h>
using namespace llvm;
constexpr const char TEST_FILE[] = "file.bc";
absl::flat_hash_map<std::string, size_t> order;
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const Function& a, const Function& b) {
        return order[a.getName().data()] < order[b.getName().data()];
    }
};
int main() {
    auto context = LLVMContext{};
    SMDiagnostic err;
    auto module = parseIRFile(TEST_FILE, err, context);
    auto& list  = module->getFunctionList();
    list.sort(Compare());
    WriteBitcodeToFile(*module, llvm::outs());
    // get all functions and adjust order according to symbol order
    // wrtie back to a valid module bitcode file
}
```

will it break some dependency relations?

Comment: WriteBitcodeToFile(*module, llvm::outs(), true);

Comment: when I diff the output ELF, they seems to have no difference at all?

Comment: Have you tried running the module?

Comment: yes. I output them to a dynamic lib (which contains `malloc` symbol) and run some test with LD_PRELOAD. Since the ELF output actually have no difference, the changed library works fine for sure.

Comment: perhaps it is my order's problem:
```c++
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const Function& a, const Function& b) {
        return rand() & 1;
    }
};
```
I see the difference using a random sort.

Comment: @droptop so what do you mean by running the module? will there be some other problems to concern about? and I am not sure whether the function order in the IR will be preserved in the final output.

Comment: I still don't get your question. LLVM doesn't care about the order of function definitions. And I think you confirmed that with your dynamic lib.

Comment: I confirmed again with `objdump` just now; llvm may refer to my module list somehow; but the layout is reordered by llvm itself; that is the first symbol is the same, then everything is re-ordered. So is there a possible way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I guess so.....

Comment: I'm just wondering where is the idea of "ordered functions == better locality" comes from?

Comment: @AlexDenisov we will use PH or C^3 algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the functions in IR in general does not define the order of functions in the final binary. Even more, the linker is free to reorder functions as necessary. And typically it's the linker job to improve the locality of the functions. LLD has some code for this already.

Comment: PH and C^3 algorithms are based on runtime profile sampling, which require us to provide our own order.

Comment: Maybe I can ask compiler to emit function-sections which can be reordered by the linker?